# Numbering equations inside left brace

Tags: numbering, cases, braces, subequations

Please,
How can I write three numbering equations with left brace. Usually I use "\numcases" but with a specific springer template this gives a different color text and different numbering position.[image: e]

I also try with "empheq", but it results not numbered equations.

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
&\psi_{\delta}^{-},\psi_{\delta}^{+}\equiv 1\text{ respectively on }K_{\delta}^{-},K_{\delta}^{+},\label{eq3.3}\\
&0 \leq\psi_{\delta}^{-},\psi_{\delta}^{+}\leq 1,\label{eq3.4}\\
&\text{Supp}(\psi_{\delta}^{-})\cap\text{Supp}(\psi_{\delta}^{+})\equiv\emptyset.\label{eq3.5}
\end{empheq}
Moreover
\begin{equation}\label{eq3.6}
\Vert\psi_{\delta}^{-}\Vert_{S}\leq\delta,\ \Vert\psi_{\delta}^{+}\Vert_{S}\leq\delta,
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: *Which* Springer template do you employ? Which packages -- other than `cases` -- do you load?

Comment: Since the odd behavior using Springer is probably deliberate, I wouldn't try to change it.

Comment: % This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals. Springer Heidelberg

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with `witharrrows`. This package provides a environment `{DispWithArrows}` similar to the environment `{align}` of `amsmath` but with some other features (among them the possibility to add arrow, as the name says).

In `{DispWithArrows}`, it's possible to add text before a brace regrouping the equations. This text is added in an optional argument (between angular brackets `<` and `>`). In this optional argument is provided with no content, only the brace is added. That's what I have done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{DispWithArrows}<>
&\psi_{\delta}^{-},\psi_{\delta}^{+}\equiv 1\text{ respectively on }K_{\delta}^{-},K_{\delta}^{+},\label{eq3.3}\\
&0 \leq\psi_{\delta}^{-},\psi_{\delta}^{+}\leq 1,\label{eq3.4}\\
&\text{Supp}(\psi_{\delta}^{-})\cap\text{Supp}(\psi_{\delta}^{+})\equiv\emptyset.\label{eq3.5}
\end{DispWithArrows}
Moreover
\begin{equation}\label{eq3.6}
\Vert\psi_{\delta}^{-}\Vert_{S}\leq\delta,\ \Vert\psi_{\delta}^{+}\Vert_{S}\leq\delta,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: ! witharrows error: "expl3 too old".

Comment: @M.A : You should update your LaTeX installation completely. It's always a good thing to have a LaTeX installation up-to-date.

Comment: Do you mean [Bibdesk, Tex live Utility and Tex shop]?

Comment: You should update TeXLive. There is a major version of TeXLive each year. TeXLive 2020 has been released in April. I don't use TeXLive (I use MikTeX) but I have been told that you should do a kind of desinstallation of TeXLive before reinstallation of the new version (2020).